# Make node show stack trace after EventEmitter warning

Tags: node.js

I have this error:

```
(node:11164) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

No stack trace is given so I have no idea which event might be the culprit.

I tried to work around it by overriding `console.warn` but the stack trace at that point is of no use since `console.warn` is not called when the listener is added but some arbitrary time afterwards.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This changed with Node v6 (or possibly with v5).

Previously, a stack trace was shown automatically, now you have to generate one yourself:

```
process.on('warning', e => console.warn(e.stack));
```

Documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_warning).

Comment: Your es6 is clean +1

Comment: spent more than enough time just to find this simple solution!

Comment: You should also be able to use the command line flag `--trace-warnings` to get the same behavior.